# Is the list of questions differently cached, on the meta site?

Tags: support, questions, meta

I noticed that when I ask a question on this meta site, and then I click on the "Questions" link, I don't immediately see the question I asked; sometimes I need to click again on the same link, and sometimes (as happened few minutes ago), I have to click on different links before to see the question I asked in the list of the questions.
I have also tried hard-reloading the page (which would mean holding the <kbd>opt</kbd> key while clicking on the reload button), without any result.

As I don't seem to have this problem on the main site (any SE site), are questions on meta sites cached differently?

I normally use Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens also in the main site to me, and in the others SE as well. I don't use Safari, and it happens anyway, so I don't think this is a bug. I always thought it was the system getting the question "archived", more or less.